# N1QL join with same Bucket with some logic

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have below json.

First Campaign

```
"campaign|1000":{
  "_id": 1000,
  "_type": "Campaign",
  "country": 14,
  "created": "2016-03-08T18:30:00.000Z",
  "user": 45
  "bids":[{
          click:123     
         },
        {
           click:50
        }
         ]
}
```

second USER

```
"User|257"{
  "IMId": "",
  "IMType": 0,
  "_id": 257,
  "_type": "User",
  "children:[1,4,45,67,106]
  "roles":[4]
  "email": "krishn@inheritx.com",
}
```

Now I need to join this json  base on who has roles=[4] and join it children with campaign.  here **children** is user like child **45 means "User|45"**
I am trying below query

```
select Users._id,count(Campaign._id) total from Inheritx Campaign 
join Inheritx Users on keys("User|"|| TOSTRING(Campaign.`user`))
join reachEffect realted_users on keys ARRAY "User|" || TOSTRING FOR  
c IN Users.children END  where Campaign._type="Campaign" and              
Users.roles=[4] group by Users._id
```

**But I need to join with campaign and children of user whose users has roles is 4**
I need **output** like below

```
{
 user:257
 clicks:157
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options.

(1) You can start with campaign, join to users, and then filter on roles afterwards.

(2) You can start with users, filter on roles, and then use an INDEX JOIN to join users to campaigns.

See https://dzone.com/articles/join-faster-with-couchbase-index-joins

Comment: can you give me example for this query. my need is little different.

Comment: Hi @krishnpatel, you can post here on Stack Overflow, or at the Couchbase forums under N1QL category. We can help you in both places. More importantly, take a N1QL course or read the docs.

Comment: I want to use second options but I can not understand how to do it.
in First options if i join with user then how i can join with user child. child is also users.

Comment: plase make a query for me

Comment: Edit your question to put sample inputs and sample results from those same inputs. The actual results you expect.

Comment: can you help me for this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41224156/need-to-create-index-on-some-queries-on-couchbase-n1ql ??

Comment: I have improved my questions. please help me

Comment: Where is the number 157 coming from? I am sorry, please review your question from the beginning to the end. If it is not clear to an outsider, will be hard to help you.